# php add image from computer to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, web

i want the php to only send image but i dont why i am also getting code with the image if you see the results in the image provided. And please help me more with this project : https://slate.sheridancollege.ca/d2l/common/viewFile.d2lfile/Database/ODIxOTQyNw/Assignment%204.docx?ou=352080

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Your Tim Horton's Order</title>
</head>``
<body bgcolor="#E5E59F">
<h1>Thank You For Your Order. Here you go:</h1>
<section>
    <?php 
        $coffee = $_REQUEST['coffee'];
    $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
    $cream = $_REQUEST['cream'];
    $sugar = $_REQUEST['sugar'];
    $coffeeC = 1;
    $creamC = 1;
    $sugarC = 1;
    for ($sub = 1; $sub <= $coffee; $sub++){
        echo $smallCup;
    }
    echo '<img src="cup.jpg" alt="" height="80" width="50" >';
    echo '<img src="cup.jpg" alt="" height="80" width="50" >';
    echo '<img src="cup.jpg" alt="" height="80" width="50" >';
    echo '<img src="cup.jpg" alt="" height="80" width="50" >';

     ?>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by also getting code. You should also copy what your final html looks like

Comment: You did not install PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your php snippet at http://www.writephponline.com/ and it seems to show the images correctly without code.

If your display is similar to the following syntaxes, you may be missing a PHP installation.

';**[your img]** echo '';**[your img]** echo '';**[your img]** echo '';**[your img]** ?>

If this is not the problem, perhaps sharing your display will help me give you a better answer.

**NOTE: the link you provided requires authorization for viewing.